Multiple plugins with ROS2 node in gazebo simulation
I am currently struggling  with ROS2 Iron and Gazebo Fortress when attaching multiple plugins to a robot that include a ros node.
The first plugin I am using with my robot is ign_ros2_control::IgnitionROS2ControlPlugin which works fine by itself. The second plugin I want to use is a custom plugin that exposes a ROS2 service. For this plugin I use almost the same initialization procedure for the ROS2 node as done in ign_ros2_control_plugin.cpp. This is the relevant code:
  if (!rclcpp::ok())
  {
    rclcpp::init(0, nullptr);
  }

  node_ = rclcpp::Node::make_shared("test_plugin");
  executor_ = std::make_shared<rclcpp::executors::MultiThreadedExecutor>();
  executor_->add_node(node_);
  stop_ = false;
  auto spin = [this]()
    {
      while (rclcpp::ok() && !this->dataPtr->stop_) {
        this->dataPtr->executor_->spin_once();
      }
    };
  thread_executor_spin_ = std::thread(spin);

But whenever I attach this custom plugin to my robot the diffdrive plugins fails to load properly. Any idea why that could be?
The biggest difference I can see is that I don't use a separate class handling the data for my plugin like IgnitionROS2ControlPluginPrivate for the IgnitionROS2ControlPlugin. Could this be related?

I have run into this issue as well. The problem arises from the fact that the ros2 control plugin initializes rclcpp with a params file flag that points to the controller yaml file that is needed for the controller manager to properly launch the controllers. However it only initializes rclcpp when it is not already initialized. If you custom plugin is loaded first it will initialize rclcpp with no arguments and the controller manager node won't have the correct parameters. The easiest work around is to add those parameters to the initialization inside of the system plugin:
std::vector<std::string> arguments = {"--ros-args"};

arguments.push_back(RCL_PARAM_FILE_FLAG);

arguments.push_back(controller_yaml_path);
  
std::vector<const char *> argv;
for (const auto & arg : arguments) {
  argv.push_back(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(arg.data()));
}
  
if (!rclcpp::ok(conveyor_context)){
  rclcpp::init(static_cast<int>(argv.size()), argv.data());
}

replace controller_yaml_path with the absolute path to your controller yaml file. You can use ament_index_cpp::get_package_share_directory to get the share directory of your package.
It is a bit of a hack but it does seem to work.

Thanks Justin. I was also able to fix it by creating a shared-executor singleton class which is initialized by the ros2 control plugin but I like your approach much better!
